# Eclipse Axis2 Webservice Client

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I am trying to create a `web service client` from `WSDL` using `Axis2` in `Eclipse`. But I am getting below error.

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanHelperWriter.getAsFieldName(JavaBeanHelperWriter.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanHelperWriter.writeMetaData(JavaBeanHelperWriter.java:325)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanHelperWriter.writeFileBody(JavaBeanHelperWriter.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaWriter.generate(JavaWriter.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanWriter.writeFileBody(JavaBeanWriter.java:257)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaWriter.generate(JavaWriter.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanWriter.generate(JavaBeanWriter.java:1405)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaTypeWriter.generate(JavaTypeWriter.java:113)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaGeneratorFactory$Writers.generate(JavaGeneratorFactory.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.generateTypes(Parser.java:547)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.generate(Parser.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.access$000(Parser.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:362)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, `wsdl2java` (more specifically, `JavaBeanHelperWriter`) seems to be failing when it's generating the source for XML metadata. Here, some XML element seems to have a `null` name property. Could you share the WSDL or related XSD files (or check the elements yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the SOAP-UI is the best way to generate an axis2 web service client from wsdl. Check the link below.

http://java.dzone.com/tips/generating-client-java-code